# Fetched data from Rest API does not appear in the browser in React

Tags: reactjs, rest, api

I am trying to fetch data, or in this case, a joke from a rest [api](https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2#getting-started) by making an xhlhttprequest. The joke is a single object. I add the single joke that is fetched to the state array which I initialized. However, the joke is not being displayed in the browser, and in console, no errors appear.  In the render portion, I tried to iterate through the single object array that should have been created after each call.  Could someone tell me what is the issue and why it is not rendering in the browser?

```
import React from 'react';


 class DadJokesApi extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoaded: false,
            error: null,
            jokes: []
        }
    }
 componentDidMount() 
 { 
     this.getData() 
}

 getData() { 
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest() 
     xhr.addEventListener('load', () => { 
         if(xhr.readyState === 4){
             if(xhr.status === 200){
                 var response = xhr.responseText,
                 json = JSON.parse(response);

                 this.setState( prev =>({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    jokes: [...prev.jokes,json]

                 }))

             } else {
                 this.setState({
                     isLoaded: true,
                     error: xhr.responseText
                 })
             }
         }
      }) 
     xhr.open('GET', ' https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/any', true) 
     xhr.send();
    }
    render() { 
        var body;
        if(!this.state.isLoaded){
            body = <div>...Loading</div>;
        } else if (this.state.error) {
            body = <div>Error occurred { this.state.error} </div>
        } else {
            var jokes = this.state.jokes.map(
                joke => <div key={joke.id} className="jokesdisplay">{jokes}</div>
            );
            body = <div>{jokes}</div> 
        }
    return body;
     }
    }
    export default DadJokesApi;
```

Comment: Can I ask why you're using `XMLHttpRequest` and not [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)? Fetch is just a wrapper around `XMLHttpRequest` and is much more user-friendly

Comment: @TomOakley The documentation for this particular api states that the only way to communicate with this API is by using XMLHttpRequest. When I console log it, the jokes appear in the console, I am just having an issue displaying it as text in the browser.

https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2#getting-started

Comment: thanks for clarifying, just wanted to check there was a reason for not using fetch

Comment: @TomOakley NP- I have used fetch, axios before, but as part of my learning, I wanted to try this method and see how it goes. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering all of the jokes `{jokes}` (which is `undefined`) inside each `div`. You need to just put the `setup` and `delivery` (or whatever you need) of one joke in the `div`.

Instead of:

```
<div key={joke.id} className="jokesdisplay">
  {jokes}
</div>
```

Use:

```
<div key={joke.id} className="jokesdisplay">
  {joke.setup} {joke.delivery}
</div>
```

Now, the full `render` method might look like:

```
render() {
  var body;
  if (!this.state.isLoaded) {
    body = <div>...Loading</div>;
  } else if (this.state.error) {
    body = <div>Error occurred {this.state.error} </div>;
  } else {
    var jokes = this.state.jokes.map(joke => (
      <div key={joke.id} className="jokesdisplay">
        {joke.setup} {joke.delivery}
      </div>
    ));
    body = <div>{jokes}</div>;
  }
  return body;
}
```

I put the working version in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-frost-7msrn?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're trying to render `jokes` inside of a div:

```js
<div key={joke.id} className="jokesdisplay">
  {jokes}
</div>
```

Which will not work since jokes is undefined, but you cannot also use joke here since you cannot render objects inside React components. What you have to do is render the text inside of `joke` object, like this

```js
<div key={joke.id} className="jokesdisplay">
  {jokes.setup}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong here:

```
            var jokes = this.state.jokes.map(
            joke => <div key={joke.id} className="jokesdisplay">{jokes}</div>
```

You should not be referencing {jokes} inside the map callback, it should be something like {joke.text}